# Set multiple Button in Android Listview with one listener?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, listener

I set 3 ToggleButton in a listview. When one Button is checked another two will be unchecked. But its not working. When I checked one button other two button unchecked  from other rows. But I want to uncheck the other two buttons from that row.

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Salat>{

    private Activity context;
    private Salat[] salat;

    TextView salatName;
    ToggleButton prayedButton;
    ToggleButton prayedLateButton;
    ToggleButton missedButton;
    final DB db = new DB(context);



    public MyListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, Salat[] salat) {
        super(context, R.layout.salat_listview, salat);
        this.context = (Activity) context;
        this.salat = salat;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.salat_listview, null, true);

        salatName = (TextView) listview.findViewById(R.id.salat_name);
        prayedButton = (ToggleButton) listview.findViewById(R.id.prayed_button);
        prayedLateButton = (ToggleButton) listview.findViewById(R.id.prayed_late_button);
        missedButton = (ToggleButton) listview.findViewById(R.id.missed_button);

        salatName.setText(getItem(position).getName());


        prayedButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(buttonListener);
        prayedLateButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(buttonListener);
        missedButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(buttonListener);



        prayedButton.setTag(position);
        prayedLateButton.setTag(position);
        missedButton.setTag(position);


        return listview;
    }

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener buttonListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(compoundButton.getId() == prayedButton.getId()){
                compoundButton.setChecked(b);
                prayedLateButton.setChecked(!b);
                missedButton.setChecked(!b);
            }
            else if(compoundButton.getId() == prayedLateButton.getId()){
                compoundButton.setChecked(b);
                prayedButton.setChecked(!b);
                missedButton.setChecked(!b);
            }
            else if(compoundButton.getId() == missedButton.getId()){
                compoundButton.setChecked(b);
                prayedButton.setChecked(!b);
                prayedLateButton.setChecked(!b);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

[image: UIScreenshot]

I know this is the wrong way. But how can I do this in listView. Maybe there is no way to solve this with `getTag()` or position.

Comment: your question is unclear. Do you want to uncheck all items in listview or only that particular item?

Comment: No. When one button is checked from one row other two button will unchecked from that row. please see the screenshot.

Comment: then your approach is correct. getView() method will work with 1 item at a time

Comment: Can you please give me a solution or another way to do this.

Comment: try the answer I gave

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but should work
try this,
Android studio might tell you to make the variables final.

**UPDATED**

```
 public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private Activity context;
        private Salat[] salat;

        TextView salatName;
        ToggleButton prayedButton;
        ToggleButton prayedLateButton;
        ToggleButton missedButton;
        final DB db = new DB(context);



        public MyListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, Salat[] salat) {
            super(context, R.layout.salat_listview, salat);
            this.context = (Activity) context;
            this.salat = salat;
        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View listview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.salat_listview, null, true);

            salatName = (TextView) listview.findViewById(R.id.salat_name);
            prayedButton = (ToggleButton) listview.findViewById(R.id.prayed_button);
            prayedLateButton = (ToggleButton) listview.findViewById(R.id.prayed_late_button);
            missedButton = (ToggleButton) listview.findViewById(R.id.missed_button);

            salatName.setText(getItem(position).getName());




           prayedButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    prayedButton.setChecked(true);
                    prayedLateButton.setChecked(false);
                    missedButton.setChecked(false);
                }
            });

           prayedLateButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    prayedButton.setChecked(false);
                    prayedLateButton.setChecked(true);
                    missedButton.setChecked(false);
                }
            });

           missedButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    prayedButton.setChecked(false);
                    prayedLateButton.setChecked(false);
                    missedButton.setChecked(true);
                }
            });



            return listview;
        }

    @Override
    public Salat getItem(int position){
       return salat[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
       return salat.length;
    }
```

Comment: I checked this before. But same problem. Not working for same row.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: what is the exact problem? what happens if prayButton is clicked?

Comment: When I clicked prayButton other two button unchecked but from other row( I mean from other List item). Check the screenshoot

Comment: I think your problem is in the adapter class. Have you pasted your complete adapter in the question?

Comment: It will be salart.length  not sala.length();   But still not solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I find a soluton. Just take an array of 3 buttons.

```
package com.ahmed.aziz.salattracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.Date;

public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Salat>{

    private Activity context;
    private Salat[] salat;

    TextView salatName;
    ToggleButton[] prayedButton = new ToggleButton[5];
    ToggleButton[] prayedLateButton = new ToggleButton[5];
    ToggleButton[] missedButton = new ToggleButton[5];
    final DB db = new DB(context);



    public MyListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, Salat[] salat) {
        super(context, R.layout.salat_listview, salat);
        this.context = (Activity) context;
        this.salat = salat;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.salat_listview, null, true);

        salatName = (TextView) listview.findViewById(R.id.salat_name);
        prayedButton[position] = (ToggleButton) listview.findViewById(R.id.prayed_button);
        prayedLateButton[position] = (ToggleButton) listview.findViewById(R.id.prayed_late_button);
        missedButton[position] = (ToggleButton) listview.findViewById(R.id.missed_button);

        salatName.setText(getItem(position).getName());


        prayedButton[position].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    prayedLateButton[position].setChecked(!b);
                    missedButton[position].setChecked(!b);
                }

            }
        });
        prayedLateButton[position].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    prayedButton[position].setChecked(!b);
                    missedButton[position].setChecked(!b);
                }
            }
        });
        missedButton[position].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    prayedButton[position].setChecked(!b);
                    prayedLateButton[position].setChecked(!b);
                }

            }
        });


        return listview;
    }

}
```

Comment: Good, you found a solution!